# Javascript - Masking a password on a JS alert box

Tags: javascript

I have the following

```
var validate=prompt("Enter your PIN","Enter your PIN");
```

This works fine except it shows the password when typing it.

Is there any way to mask the password being entered?

Cheers,

Comment: don't do password validation through client side...it's just fail in so many ways.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there is no way to mask `prompt` box. You will have to use some other **custom solution** or use `password` input box instead.

*If you want to do validation of password, do it on the server-side not client-side.*

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a prompt window and accept a password, you might want to use this plugin along with jquery. Check out example 9 on http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/index.php and use `type="password"` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to hide the password.JS load on the client side.
We can easily find the password by checking the source code.

Here is an example. Check it out yourself
http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jpass.htm